# Can a CGAL's shared library (lib[name].so) be used on a computer without CGAL's installed?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, shared-libraries, cgal

I managed to create a shared library that use CGAL 5.0.1 extensively. Now, my question is, would it be possible if I take this new shared library to other computer without CGAL already installed.

From CGAL's [website](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html):

> Since CGAL version 5.0, CGAL is header-only be default, which means
>   that there is no need to compile CGAL or its libraries before it can
>   be used.
>
> This page is for advanced users that have a good reason to still use
>   the old way. If this is not your case, head over back to the page
>   Getting Started with CGAL.

The way I understand this is that since there is no need to compile CGAL, there is no need to install CGAL if we already have the shared library. Is this correct? Thanks, I'm pretty new to C++ and all the related stuffs.

Comment: Why not try it? (it should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

When you use CGAL header only, no CGAL shared library is built.
When you build a shared library, you must distribute it together with your executable. The user of your application does not have to install CGAL.

What I write here is not CGAL specific.